Unable Microsoft graph api delegate permission for send email in Razorpages
Currently I'm working on an emailfunctionality in Razorpages.
I made a button on a details page for orders, and I want to send an email to the user.
All my users are in the Azure AD.
This is my handler :
     public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSubmitEmail(string emailTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      {

          await _exchangeOnlineClient.SendDeniedMail("Subject", User.GetEmail(), emailTo, cancellationToken);
          return new JsonResult(new { successMessage = "Email verstuurd" });
      }

My SendDeniedMail method :
        public async Task SendDeniedMail(string subject, string mailFrom, string mailTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string content = "content";
            var authProvider = new CustomTokenCredentialAuthProvider(_exchangeOnlineConfiguration.TenantId, _exchangeOnlineConfiguration.ClientId, _exchangeOnlineConfiguration.ClientSecret);
 
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var sendMailPostRequestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody()
            {
                Message = new Message()
                {
                    Subject = subject,
                    Body = new ItemBody()
                    {
                        Content = content,
                        ContentType = BodyType.Text
                    },
                    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                    {
                        new Recipient()
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress()
                            {
                                Address = mailTo
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                SaveToSentItems = false
            };

            await graphClient.Users[mailFrom].SendMail.PostAsync(sendMailPostRequestBody);
        }

I wrote a custom token provider ( removed the tenantId and other sensitive stuff) :
  public class CustomTokenCredentialAuthProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
    {
        private ClientSecretCredential _clientSecretCredential;
        private IConfidentialClientApplication _confidentialClientApplicationBuilder;

        public CustomTokenCredentialAuthProvider(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            _clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("https://login.microsoftonline.com")
            {
                Path = "tenantId"
            };

            _confidentialClientApplicationBuilder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(tenantId).WithClientId(clientId).WithClientSecret(clientSecret).WithAuthority(uriBuilder.Uri).Build();

        }

        public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(RequestInformation request, Dictionary<string, object>? additionalAuthenticationContext = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var result = await _confidentialClientApplicationBuilder.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {result.AccessToken}");
        }
    }

The result is filled with an token.
However when I use this token :
Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
My azure configuration : 

So... How do I correctly implement this delegated permissions flow ?
Extra information :
The users are signed-in through a Duende identity server 6. This is a standalone application which is connected with the Azure AD I'm talking with in this portal.
I'm not allowed to use Applicationpermissions by my system administrator.
I have also tried to change the scope to api://{ID}/.default  or api://{ID}/Mail.Send.Delegated
But this results in :

{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope api://{ID}/Mail.Send.Delegated is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed

But this is in my understanding the wrong authenticationflow.

Here's the sending email API which you are using, as we can see, it requires Mail.Send API permission(Delegated or Application) so that Graph API could send email on behalf of current signed-in user(Delegated, /me/sendMail) or on behalf of the appplication(/users/userId/sendMail).

In the screenshot you shared, you added the Delegated API permission, but you set the scope as https://graph.microsoft.com/.default which is used for Application API permission. I'm not sure which type of authentication you want to use. Because you didn't share the authentication scheme which should be defined in Program.cs
If you require a user to sign in first and then send email on behalf of this user, then you need to change the scope to Mail.Send instead and use  other AuthProvider. This also requires to integrate Azure AD authentication into your application so that users could sign in with their ms account.
If you don't want to require users to sign in, or you just want to have an e.g. admin account to have the ability to send email, then you might use the Application API permission. Then you need to add Application type of Mail.Send. But this requires admin consent.

